# Creating Pull Requests with VS Code UI

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm used to creating Pull Requests with VS Code UI (Source Control section). I find this very useful since you can create and push PR Request in a few seconds, and you don't have to memorize Git commands.

[image]

But recently, this option started disappearing after VS Code initialize everything.

The **GitHub Pull Request** extension also does not have option to `Create a new PR` when I open its section. It only opens a preview mode of the most recent PR.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a fix for this. It looks like it's some bug.

So, in the question I said that **GitHub Pull Request** extension also does not have option to Create a new PR when I open its section. It only opens a `review mode` of the most recent PR.

In order to return things back to normal, you have to **exit** a `review mode` from **GitHub Pull Request** section.

[image]

After that, you should be able to `Create a new PR` from Source Control section.

Answer (score 0):

The **GitHub** Pull Request and issues feature is part of an independent extension provided for VSCode.

Installing this extension will add a separate tab to your sidebar with options to look at the PRs/Issues assigned to you along with Creating a PR.

**Extension**: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github

**Official Documentation**: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github#_pull-requests

Edited:

Press the highlighted tab:
[image]

Comment: If you check my second image, you will see that extension also. That extension should open from the button on my first image, in Source Control section.